# Android OkHttpClient always calls onFailure method

Tags: android

```
HttpUrl.Builder httpBuider =              HttpUrl.parse("some url here").newBuilder();
        httpBuider.addQueryParameter("email", email);
        httpBuider.addQueryParameter("password", password);    
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().
                url(httpBuider.build()).build();

        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() { ... public void onFailure() {...} ...}
```

So this is the code that I use in android project. The method onFailure is always called, and the url is not accessed from the emulator. I have put the application on a real device and it seems to work, but from the emulator it doesn't, and I have internet connection. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think normally OkHttp offers the error code when in `onFailure`, try logging it to see what's wrong

Comment: Do you have added the runtime permissions?